# Find formula parameters with given data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am looking for anything able to fit a formula (i.e. find optimal parameters) to some data (say, t and f(t)).

[image]

In that example, I want to find something so I get a, b, c and d, given some t, f(t) values.

Any tips welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should help. I don't know your exact output, but making a function is probably the most useful option without more details.

```
def formula_x(t):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0
    e = 0
    formula = a*t^b*(e^(-c*t))+d
    return formula
print(formula_x(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def hugershoff(t, a, b, c, d):
    return a * t**b * np.exp(-c*t) + d
```

then with my data (from a dataframe):

```
popt, _ = curve_fit(hugershoff, data['X'], data['Y'])
```

which led to my 4 formula parameters. However, the values are completely nuts. If I fix some of the params (example:

```
def hugershoff_tambo(t, b, d):
    # b = peak intensity
    return 0.5 * t**b * np.exp(-0.013*t) + d
```

)
I get much better params.

In my example I want to fit a curve to the milk yield of dairy cows given the amount of days they are from their calf.